# How does one target all divs of any webpage but differentiate them in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

So I am trying to create an extension in Chrome (a prototype for a project that I am doing) that targets all of the `<div>` tags of any web page, hides them or rather doesn't display them until the user clicks the mouse (further explained below).  So typing a url into the browser yields a white page.  The person clicks, and the first `<div>` appears (probably the mast head or menu).  The user clicks again and the second `<div>` appears.

I have gotten to the point where I can hide or show all `<div>`'s (the obvious easy part) but I am not sure how to go about targeting each since every website has different id's for them while still using the `<div>` tag. This is what I need the most help with.

This is part of a grander operation called the Web Crank. It's just a physical crank that controls the speed by which a web page loads. Each time you make one full rotation of the crank, one section (the first `<div>`) of the web page loads. The faster you go, the quicker the page loads.

I hope this is clear enough.  I am a newbie when it comes to this, but I have done some minor coding in the past and it's not such a big deal.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How can you guarantee all websites have `div` for their containers? I think you're better off showing them by descendant.. i.e. show the parents first, then children, then grandchildren etc

Comment: Good point.  I struggled with that one and for sake of simplicity, settled on div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using just the DOM without any libraries, iterate over this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div")
```

gets you all the `<div>`s on the page. To iterate over them, use a for loop:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  /* stuff */
}
```

In jQuery (which you probably ought not to use in a Chrome plugin...):

```
$("div").each(function(i) { /* whatever */ });
```

What you basically want to do is iterate through all the `<div>`s and hide them all, then as you crank the crank, have that call an iterator that goes through and adds things back in. Probably what I'd do is create a FIFO queue ([like this?](http://safalra.com/web-design/javascript/queues/)) of 'to-be-cranked' elements as you are hiding them, and then as the crank operation fires (however you do that), start pulling items off the queue and showing them again.

As a side issue, why `<div>`s though and not just all block-level elements? You probably want to search for `<div>`, `<p>`, `<blockquote>`, `<ol>`, `<ul>`, `<dl>` and `<table>` elements too.

Comment: Compromise: I've put a note saying you ought not use jQuery in a Chrome plugin.

Comment: Ok, deal. I think that including a library that makes cross browser development easier doesn't make much sense when coding JavaScript for one browser.

Comment: @alex, I think JQuery makes *all* browser development easier.

Comment: Thanks Tom and Alex.  If then I were to expand the search for other elements like <p> and <ol> and <ul>, etc, would it just be a matter of of including them all in the document.getElementsByTagName() method?
So: document.getElementsByTagName("div", "p", "ul"...)

Comment: Admittedly, this extension will only be used remotely from one computer, so cross browser development is unnecessary.

Comment: Chaz: no. you would have to construct an array and add all the elements to it with separate getElementsByTagName calls and then iterate over that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get every div on a page, just stick them in an array and now you can index them.

Answer (score -1):

if you can use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com) then use the [.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) keyword. that will allow you to itterate through the collection and gather data about them, show/hide etc.

Comment: I don't know if including jQuery would be best for a Chrome plugin.

Comment: @ItzWarty I love Bobince's articles! However I think it'd be respectful to link to his article than hotlink his image.